# Ошибка use of undefined type

Tags: c++, классы, visual-c++, c++11

Есть два класса TextQuery и QueryResult. Первый использует в методах второй и второй соответственно первый.

```
class QueryResult;

class TextQuery {
//Fields
public:
//OtherMethods

    QueryResult query(const string& sought)const {
        /*Some code*/
        if (/*predicate*/)
            return QueryResult(sought, nodata, file);
        else
            return QueryResult(sought, loc->second, file);
    }
};

class QueryResult {
private:
    //Fields
public:
    QueryResult(string s, shared_ptr<set<TextQuery::line_no>> p, shared_ptr<vector<string>> f) :sought(s), lines(p), file(f) {}
};
```

На этапе компиляции возникает три ошибки 'use of undefined type QueryResult' в методе query класса TextQuery

Comment: Вынесете определение метода `query` после определения класса `QueryResult` или вообще сделайте этот класс внутренним.

Comment: вынеси определение `TextQuery::query()` позже определения `QueryResult`.

Comment: В чем выражается зависимость второго от первого? Если только в `TextQuery::line_no`, то не проще ли от нее избавиться?

Comment: @VTT Спасибо, помогло. Не могли бы вы пожалуйста объяснить мне мою принципиальную ошибку?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Спасибо, помогло. Не могли бы вы пожалуйста объяснить мне мою принципиальную ошибку?

Comment: @Денис в строгих терминах С++ объяснять не хочется, но на пальцах ошибка очевидна: ты пытаешься создать экземпляр класса *ДО* того как определяешь сам класс.

Comment: неполное определение не всегда можно использовать. К примру для создания,  определения метода, описания переменной или преобразования типа нельзя. Для описания переменной указателя на этот класс или для описания прототипа функции использующей его в списке аргументов  - можно

Answer (score 0):

Вначале нужно просто объявить эти два класса, но не расписывать методы - это должен быть файл .h, а саму реализацию поместить в .cpp

```
class A;
class B;

class A {
  public: void foo();
}

class B {
  public: void bar();
}



void A::foo() {
  B *b = new B();
  b->bar();
}


void B::bar() {
  A *a = new A();
  a->foo();
}
```